# What is the maximal ideal space of $H^\infty$?

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras

What is the spectrum of $H^\infty$, the Banach algebra of  all bounded holomorphic functions in the open unit disk $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z| <1 \} $?

Comment: Is there any advantage for the rather odd term *pre-Banach algebra*? Such objects are usually called normed algebras.

Have you heard of the algebra $H^\infty$?

Comment: @TomekKania I was motivated by the terminology pre Hilbert space.

Comment: ??? The space of bounded holomorphic functions is already complete! It's a Banach algebra.

Comment: @Yaddle  I mean the Maximal ideal space of the algebra. In some references,  this space is called the spectrum.

Comment: @Yaddle One should be careful about saying this word doesn't mean that. because words mean many different things. The spectrum of a Banach algebra is the maximal ideal space - perfectly standard definition.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  Ah yes thank you it is  complete I revise my question. but what is its spectrum

Comment: I revised it for you - feel free to un-revise...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  many thanks for your revisions.

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple description of the spectrum of the algebra of bounded holomorphic functions in the disk (known as $H^\infty$). It's an Axiom-of-Choice-ish thing.

If $|z|<1$ then $f\mapsto f(z)$ is a complex homomorphism, so the open disk is contained in the spectrum in a natural way. The Corona Theorem says that the disk is dense. This is one of the huge theorems that made Lennart Carleson *Lennart Carleson*. Carleson's proof is very nasty, but the techniques led to a lot of stuff about the unit disk. See Garnett *Bounded Analytic Functions*. Somewhat later Tom Wolfe gave a much simpler proof.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit*: This is an answer to the previous version of this question.

This algebra is complete; it is a simple application of Morera's theorem which you may use to show that the uniform limit of such functions is actually holomorphic. This algebra is traditionally denoted by $H^\infty$ and is highly non-separable.

For this reason, the maximal ideal space of $H^\infty$ is huge. See [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9908168v1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i was aware of the holomorficity as I wrote here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853924/the-notion-of-a-holomorphicity  but my mistake was about boundedness!